# Laravel, serviceProviders' boot method and phpunit

Tags: laravel, database, phpunit

I have a serviceProvider instantiating some classes which are then stored into a registry, this is as per the registry pattern where you then can do something like
`$registry->get('some-name')` and you get an instance of the class associated to `some-name`.

The problem is that the classes rely on the database to "initialize" the instances.

Now, when running tests, on an empty test database, they fail as the data is not there.

Of course I can't rely on phpunit data providers because those classes are instantiated when the application boots up, hence for every single testcase.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Should I consider not using the registry pattern at all?

Comment: You need to show code as I do not understand what the issue is. If not having data on the DB is the issue, then make it have it. Why can't you do that?

Comment: @matiaslauriti the problem is that the boot method of registered service providers is executed every time the app boots up and that in testing happens for every test case which means i can't mock it for every test, I should instad actually have the data in db, which is a testing anti-pattern as, AFAIK, a test db should always be empty at the beginning of the test and left empty once the test is finished.